# Cant run java to send email in linux. .NoClassDefFoundError javax/mail/Authenticator

Tags: java, linux, jar

Im trying to run in a Linux Server with Tomcat a simple java to send emails.

I have the myClass.java and the mail.jar on a directory

I already did:

```
# javac -cp mail.jar myClass.java
```

and return no error, but...

when I try to run it like this:

```
# java myClass
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: myClass. Program will exit.
```

Its strange, beacuse I run it exactly like that on Windows and it works. I also try to do a simple class with just a System.out inside and it run,

but i dont know why im not getting the Authenticator class, if I already check that it is contain in the mail.jar

Im using java 1.6.0_22

thanks! ^^

Comment: The `mail.jar` isn't magically included in your class. (Who upvotes this??)

Answer (score 0):

You included `mail.jar` in your classpath to compile it, you should also include it when you run the class.

Comment: java -cp .:mail.jar myClass

Answer (score 0):

By default when you ran your java program in command line using command such as **java MyClass**, you are running Java SE (Standard Edition) environment. The other popular environment is Java EE (Enterprise Edition).

The class which your program is complaining for (javax.mail.authentication) came from Java EE packages, and it's definitely non-existent on your runtime

The fact that you can compile your code must mean there is a dependency jar somewhere on your eclipse build path (if you use eclipse) you are not including on your runtime (eg: mail.jar)

You need to run your program such that the dependency are available on runtime, eg:

```
java -jar /path/to/mail.jar MyClass
```

Or run your program on a Java EE environment